# Facebook authentication w/o browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to make a `POST` request to the URL specified in the [Authentication Doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/) but it doesn't return a successful response:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/device?type=device_code&client_id=APPID');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3',
    CURLOPT_POST => true
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
exit(var_dump($result));
```

Where `APPID` is my application ID. It just returns a `boolean false`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This authentication method is not available for general use. From the URL you posted:

> Please note that we are currently testing Device Authentication with a
>   limited number of partners. It is not currently available for general
>   use, and we are not accepting additional applications for access.

Comment: Hmm, what could be alternatives? I'm trying to make a cron job to automatically post to a facebook page.

Comment: Why would that use-case need device auth? Follow the 'authenticating as a page' steps to get the page access token and store that for use when administering the page